# UIImage added with constraits programmatically looks chopped

Tags: ios, autolayout

I do my layout using constraints in code. My UIImages look chopped. Like this

[image]

but image is 300x300 png and has good quality

```
    var clock:UIImageView?

    clock = UIImageView()
    clock?.image = UIImage(named: "clock")
    clock?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    addSubview(clock!)
    clock!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    clock!.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(leadingAnchor, constant: 20).active = true
    clock!.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bottomAnchor, constant: -20).active = true
    clock!.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(12).active = true
    clock!.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(12).active = true
```

And this happens with all images that I add in way like above.

How to fix that ?

Comment: By chopped do you mean it looks pixelated, or that the circle isn't smooth? This can happen even if the image is big. Downsizing a large image can make it look choppy.

Comment: You are right. Problem was in big image, after size reduction everything is great. Thanks a lot!